# Lua - attempt to call method 'new' (a nil value)

Tags: oop, lua

New to Lua, trying to figure out how to do OOP using the [middleclass](https://github.com/kikito/middleclass/wiki/Quick-Example) library

main.lua:

```
require 'middleclass'
require 'Person'

local testPerson = Person:new("Sally"); //causes Runtime error: attempt to call method 'new' (a nil value)
testPerson:speak();
```

Person.lua:

```
module(..., package.seeall)
require 'middleclass'

Person = class('Person');
function Person:initialize(name)
  self.name = name;
  print("INITIALIZE: " .. self.name);
end

function Person:speak()
  print('Hi, I am ' .. self.name ..'.')
end
```

Why am I getting that error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the semicolons at the end of lines are not necessary and probably a bad habit for writing Lua code. Secondly, I changed `require 'middleclass'` to `require 'middleclass.init'` in both files and removed `module(..., package.seeall)`. After that, the example code worked just fine on my machine with Lua 5.1.4.

**main.lua**

```
require 'Person'

local testPerson = Person:new("Sally")
testPerson:speak()
```

**Person.lua**

```
require 'middleclass.init'

Person = class('Person')

function Person:initialize(name)
  self.name = name
  print("INITIALIZE: " .. self.name)
end

function Person:speak()
  print('Hi, I am ' .. self.name ..'.')
end
```

You may be including the *middleclass.lua* file directly. It is not setup to work that way. The intention is to include *middleclass/init.lua*.

If you use the two files exactly as shown above and layout your files as shown below this will work.

```
./main.lua
./Person.lua
./middleclass/init.lua
./middleclass/middleclass.lua
```

Comment: Now I get this - no file '/path/middleclass.init.lua'. To be clear, my project folder contains 4 files: main.lua, Person.lua, middleclass.lua, init.lua

Comment: Either put middleclass.lua and init.lua in a subdirectory called middleclass or just require 'init'.

Comment: ok, I put them in a subdirectory called middleclass and changed the requires to 'middleclass'. Obviously incorrect - module 'middleclass' not found:resource (middleclass.lu) does not exist in archive
 no field package.preload['middleclass']

Comment: You need to require middleclass.init as shown in the example above or add ?/init.lua to your search path.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me with this. I changed it to middleclass.init in both files. Now I get this: module 'middleclass.init' not found:resource (middleclass.init.lu) does not exist in archive
 no field package.preload['middleclass.init']

Comment: @sol I had a copy and paste error putting the code snippets in. So, take another look at the answer.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be looking in the subfolder though: /path/Person.lua:1: module 'middleclass.init' not found:resource (middleclass.init.lu) does not exist in archive
 no field package.preload['middleclass.init']
 no file '/path/middleclass.init.lua'

Comment: I got it working by moving middleclass.lua back into the root directory and changing the require to 'middleclass'

Comment: You answer does not match https://github.com/kikito/middleclass (which was linked to in the question), what implementation are you referring to?

Comment: It may have changed in the 10 years since I answered this question.

Answer (score 2):

Answer by 'Judge' above is incorrect - there is no need to include "middleclass.init" and have the folder structure shown above.

As stated on the Github project wiki, you can simply download the license and 'middleclass.lua', place these files in your code directory, then simply do

```
require("middleclass");
```

Make sure you don't have a module declaration in a file using middleclass, i.e. don't have a

```
module(...,package.seeall)
```

..for example.